# How to find a best way to connect different nodes between different unions?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Description:

There are 1000 unions, each union contains x nodes(x is a random value between 1~100).
Now we can create a connection from one node in union A to another node in union B.

The rule is:

```
1. one node only accepts just one connection. 
2. The connection must be across different unions.
```

Similarly, create such kind of connections as many as possible.

In the end, there may be several nodes left which are unable to be connected because of no other available nodes in other unions.

For example:

```
Union 1: a b c
Union 2: d e
Union 3: f g h i j
```

If we choose the following connections:

```
U1.a <-> U2.d
U1.b <-> U2.e
U1.c <-> U3.f
```

The `h i j` in union 3 will be left.

But if we use another kind of connection:

```
U1.a <-> U3.f
U1.b <-> U3.g
U1.c <-> U3.h
U2.d <-> U3.i
U2.e <-> U3.j
```

Then there will be no nodes left.

So the question is:

How can we design the algorithm to try to find the optimal solution which will make the no-connection nodes least?

Comment: I think you should also try to ask here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), where each element in the input multiset is the length of a union. Furthermore, this problem can always be solved with a simple greedy implementation that runs in O(n) time. For example, consider the following input:

```
Union 1: a a a
Union 2: b b b b b b b b b
Union 3: c c c c c c c c c c
Union 4: d d d d d d d d d d 
Union 5: e e
```

The simple greedy algorithm creates two output lists. For each union (starting with the union that has the most elements), the elements of the union are added to the shorter output list. The result is two lists like this:

```
c c c c c c c c c c b b b b b b b b b
d d d d d d d d d d a a a e e
```

The next step is to take some of the items from the end of the longer list and add them to the beginning of the shorter list. In this example two `b`s are moved:

```
c c c c c c c c c c b b b b b b b 
b b d d d d d d d d d d a a a e e
```

So, will it always work? Yes, the only exception is when one union contains more than half of the total number of items. In that case, no items are moved from the longer list.

Here's an example implementation in python:

```
inputList = [['a','a','a'],
            ['b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b'],
            ['c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c'],
            ['d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d'],
            ['e','e']]
topCount = 0
botCount = 0
topList = []
botList = []

# sort the input in descending order based on length
inputList = sorted(inputList, key=lambda x:len(x), reverse=True)

# greedy partitioning into two output lists
for itemList in inputList:
    if topCount <= botCount:
        topList += itemList
        topCount += len(itemList)
    else:
        botList += itemList
        botCount += len(itemList)

# move some elements from the end of the longer list to the beginning of the shorter list
if topList[0] != topList[-1]:
    if topCount > botCount+1:
        excess = (topCount - botCount) // 2
        botList = topList[-excess:] + botList
        topList = topList[:-excess]
    elif botCount > topCount+1:
        excess = (botCount - topCount) // 2
        topList = botList[-excess:] + topList
        botList = botList[:-excess]

print topList
print botList
```

The output is:

```
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'e', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a [matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)) where your graph is:

```
G=(V,E), 
V = {all nodes}, 
E={(u,v) | u and v not in same union}
```

It can be solved, for example by [Blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm)